# preg_replace, exact opposite of a preg_match

Tags: regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to do a `preg_replace` for the exact opposite of this `preg_match` regular expression:

```
preg_match('#^(\w+/){0,2}\w+\.\w+$#', $string);
```

So I need to replace all strings that are not valid with an empty string -> `''`

So it needs to remove the first `/` and last `/` if found, and all non-valid characters, that is the only valid characters are `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_`, `.`, and `/` (if it's not the first or last characters of the string).

How can I accomplish this with the preg_replace?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#^/|/$|[^A-Za-z0-9_./]#D', '', $subject);
```

Comment: Is that `A-z` supposed to be `A-Z`?  Just wondering and thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.  The D addresses an edge case where the string ends with /\n (slash then newline).  This / is deleted without the D and allowed with it.  It stands for PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: Ok, I can't have a / at the end of the string, so I wouldn't use this `D` right?  Thanks again.

Comment: With or without the D, a `/` at the very end is deleted.  Without the D, a string ending in /\n also has the / deleted.

Comment: I am grabbing this from an XML document, for example: `<path>/apath/anotherPath/</path>`  So it needs to remove the 2 slashes, 1 at the beginning and 1 at the end.  Would I need the `D` for this?

Comment: Also, can you tell me, how I can add `-` as a valid character if found before the `.` within this PCRE: `preg_match('#^(\w+/){0,2}\w+\.\w+$#', $string)`  Thank You...

Comment: @SoLoGHoST, If I understand right, `'#^([\w-]+/){0,2}[\w-]+\.\w+$#'`